# Hide specific product variations from unlogged users in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm trying to hide only *one* of the two variations of a product in WooCommerce for visitors that are not logged in. The ID of the variation is 139. I don't know how to add the ID (or slug) to this piece of code.

```
    <?php // Hide WooCommerce variations for non-logged-in users
    function my_theme_hide_price_not_authorized() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Hide variations
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'my_theme_disable_variation', 10 , 2 );
     }
    }

    add_action('init', 'my_theme_hide_price_not_authorized');
    // Hide product variations
    function my_theme_disable_variation() {
    return false;
    }
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** - To hide specific defined product variations from unlogged users, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_visible', 'hide_specific_product_variation', 10, 4 );
function hide_specific_product_variation( $is_visible, $variation_id, $variable_product, $variation ) {
    // Here define the variation(s) ID(s) to hide
    $variations_ids_to_hide = array('139');
    
    // For unlogged user, hide defined variations
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() && in_array($variation_id, $variations_ids_to_hide ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $is_visible;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, as you already know!

One final question: do you know if there is a way to hide the variation from the drop-down as well? Now it's inactive (which is a huge win already), so I'm happy either way.

Comment: @Lise Oups! Just changed the hook… This time specific variation should be hidden instead.